# How do I run a bash command in powershell using java and storing the output continuos stream?

Tags: java, windows, bash, powershell

I want to run from powershell somthing like:

```
String command = bash .\notify.sh
```

Which returns in output the what is listening from a gateway, and once a specific line is given back I want to store it. Any suggestion?
(I'm on Windows so this is why I need the powershell)

Comment: If you want to run a bash script on Windows, you'll need a windows port of bash installed. Not sure what powershell has to do with anything.

Comment: I have already installed it. This is why I included "bash" in the command example. When I run it manually I open the powershell, then I give the "bash" command, and the I input the final command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.